# Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation' when using spring R2DBC to connect with a mySQL server version 8

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-r2dbc

I created a new spring boot project using the IntelliJ Idea's spring initializer and checked the `Web/Spring reactive Web` and the `SQL/Spring data R2DBC` dependencies.

I also added the the dependency to the R2DBC implementation for MySQL

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the java connector

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Asking the version of the MySQL server from a console with
`select version();`
I get
`8.0.17`

The connection factory configuration is like this:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class R2dbcConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactoryOptions conf = ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                .option(DRIVER, "mysql")
                .option(HOST, "the.db.url")
                .option(PORT, 33066612)
                .option(USER, "myUserName")
                .option(PASSWORD, "myPassword")
                .option(DATABASE, "aDbName")
                .build();
        return ConnectionFactories.find(conf);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, when I run the application I get the following exception

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException: [1193] Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException: [1193] Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
```

Answers to similar questions instructed the asker to update the version of the `mysql:mysql-connector-java` to `8.+`, and according to IntelliJ the versión resolved by maven is `8.0.26`.
Curiously, if I remove the connector dependency the result is exactly the same.

So, I debbuged the R2DBC implementation to find out what is happening and I discovered that during the handshake, the `dev.miku.r2dbc.mysq.QueryFlow#initHandshake` method receives a `HandshakeRequest` message whose headers tell that the server version is "5.5.30". And that causes the R2DBC implementation to use the old "tx_isolation" system variable name instead of the new "transaction_isolation".

Why?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html says:

> The `tx_isolation` and `tx_read_only` system variables have been removed. Use `transaction_isolation` and `transaction_read_only` instead.

You checked and discovered the server version is 8.0.17. This is more authoritative than the handshake headers message.

I recommend searching your classpath for any leftover jar files with old versions of the connector. You may have both version 8.0.26 of the connector and an older version that hasn't been updated to use the new option names.

Comment: Do you know how can I check that exhaustively. The list of dependencies that IntelliJ shows does not contain other mysql connector.  Are all the transitive dependencies listed there or only the first levels?

Comment: I would add code to my app to call `conn.getMetaData()` and from the metadata object, call `getDriverVersion()`. That would prove which version of the driver is found by the CLASSPATH at runtime. Then I'd search for the jar file on the filesystem, not using IntelliJ, but using something simpler such as `find`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you solved it? I found that R2dbc mysql driver doesn't get my MySql version, because it has a check of it to ask for tx_isolation or transaction_isolation.

The solution I got was changing the driver to Jasync.

```
//DB
implementation("com.github.jasync-sql:jasync-r2dbc-mysql:2.0.4")
implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.6.0")
```

And my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbPropertiesConfig::class)
class DataSourceConfiguration {
@Configuration
    class ProdMySQLConfiguration(@Autowired val dbPropertiesConfig: DbPropertiesConfig) : AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {

        @Bean
        override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory =
                JasyncConnectionFactory(MySQLConnectionFactory(
                        com.github.jasync.sql.db.Configuration(
                                database = dbPropertiesConfig.db,
                                port = dbPropertiesConfig.port,
                                username = dbPropertiesConfig.username,
                                host = dbPropertiesConfig.host,
                                password = dbPropertiesConfig.password
                        )
                ))
    }
```

}

Taking into consideration I have that DbPropertiesConfig in my yml.

Doc/Example:
[Doc](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql)
[Example](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc#overview)

Gitter: https://gitter.im/jasync-sql/support

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).